# BigQuery event user_engagement

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery

to understand the relation between user activities in my app and the events shown in the BigQuery, I have done some experiment by navigating in my app and tried to match them with the events in BigQuery. However, I found that a event called user_engagement looks strange. Sometimes I didn't do anything in my app at that time but there are some user_engagement events shown in the BigQuery. Can somebody tell me how user_engagement event generated in BigQuery?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this is related to the events generated with the Firebase SDK. If you look at the documentation [here](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317485), user_engagement is triggered periodically while the app is in the foreground.